# Multiple Overlays

Tags: jquery, overlay

I'm trying to create a very simple page that has multiple overlayed images (3 to be exact). The images overlay happens by clicking on a button. I would like to have the first overlay close when the second button is clicked, any ideas? How can I get an existing overlay to close when another is selected using jquery?

P.S. I'm very new to this if you can't tell.